# How to proceed with logarithms in exponents like in this problem

Tags: logarithms

> The product of all the solutions of the equation $x^{1+\log_{10}x} =
>  100000x$ is $$(A)~ 10 \qquad (B)~ 10^5 \qquad (C)~ 10^{-5} \qquad
>  (D)~1$$

Is there some properties I should know to solve this?

Comment: Properties of exponents, properties of logarithms.

Comment: Take logs of both sides of the equation.  Solve for $\log_{10} x$.

Comment: Keep in mind:

$$x^{1+\log_{10} x} = x\cdot x^{\log_{10} x} = 100000x$$

This leads to 
$$x^{\log_{10} x} = 100000$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a solution then
$$\left(\frac1u\right)^{1+\log_{10}(1/u)}=\left(\frac1u\right)^{1-\log_{10}u}=u^{-1+\log_{10}u}=\frac{10000}u$$
We see that if $u$ is a solution, then so is $1/u$. Hence, the product of the solutions is $1$.

Comment: Granted that there is a solution at all.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If there is no solution, the product is 1, too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  Using the below properties, you should be able to take the $\log_{10}$ of both sides and simplify, such that you can solve for $\log_{10} x$.

- $\log_b(x^a) = a\log_b(x)$
- $\log_b(a\cdot c) = \log_b(a) \cdot \log_b(c)$
- $x^{a+b} = x^ax^b$